# Override Nextjs routes

Tags: routes, next.js

I would like to set the routes from a config file so the folder structure does not need to change if I want to change any routes. I am currently trying by adding `exportPathMap` in `next.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    exportPathMap: async function(
        defaultPathMap,
            { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId },
    ) {
      return {
          '/hello': { page: '/'},
      }
    },
}
```

But I can view the index from both locations now `/` and `/hello`. How do I set it so the routes in `next.config.js` take priority?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to access the index page from `/` path?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean @juliomalves. If the route page: '/' exists in both locations only the one in the config file should work.